# Setting breakpoints in release mode in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am using Qt creator and cdb debugger for my c++ project. I need to set some breakpoints in code and see what happens during runtime. Unfortunately because of some third party library I absolutely can not use Debug mode so I have to stick to the release mode.

In visual studio I always do such thing and use breakpoints in the release mode easily but how could I do that in Qt creator?

(Versions: Qt 5.12  / Qt creator 4.8)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and could only _partialy_ solve it by adding `CONFIG += optimize_debug` to my `.pro`. There are more options seen `mkspecs\features\default_post.prf`, you can try, but for me non of them gave me full debugging capabilities like in VS. UPD: I also have `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=/Zi` and `QMAKE_LFLAGS+= /INCREMENTAL:NO /Debug`

Comment: @mvidelgauz Thanks. I added that, didn't work. Obviously we shouldn't expect the whole debugging powers in release mode, but a breakpoint is not much. I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Learn other flags, I do have breakpoints with those that I mentioned. Another my trick: start your qt app(built with those flags) from VS, making sure `pdb` files are generated and visible to vs - works perfectly for me

Comment: I forgot one more thing that I did - hack `\mkspecs\common\msvc-desktop.conf`: find `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_OPTIMIZE_DEBUG -Zi -MD` and replace `$$QMAKE_CFLAGS_OPTIMIZE` with `$$QMAKE_CFLAGS_OPTIMIZE_DEBUG`

Comment: @mvidelgauz msvc_desktop didn't work too. Lots of *.conf files are so confusing by the way :(

Comment: Probably some other flags are different in our projects... At this point, I would give up and switch to VS method...

Comment: try  `CONFIG+=force_debug_info`

Comment: @Pedro That didn't work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a "Profile" build in Qt Creator. That will include separate debugging line information in a "Release" (optimized) build.  You can then launch it using the Debug button in Qt Creator and set breakpoints as you need.

Caveats:

- You may not be able to get the exact line you want because of optimizations by the compiler.
- You most variables will be optimized into registers, so you can't view them.  If you need to view registers, try the good, old fashion method of printing their values out with a qDebug() statement. (When in doubt, print it out.)

Comment: That simple, Nice! Yes no need to full facilities of the debug mode. Just a breakpoint solves the problems.